# Not able to get all users from Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, soap, azure-active-directory

I am using solution [mentioned here](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/599697/get-list-of-active-directory-users-in-csharp) to get all users from Active Directory however I suspect the code is pulling disabled users from our old Active Directory. The new one is Azure Active Directory. Please let me know what change is required to get below details of only active users from Azure Active Directory:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Email
4. Enterprise ID

Comment: pls correct me if I misunderstood your requirement, and I'll delete it if it's completely not related. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting all users in Azure AD can use Microsoft Graph API. Here's the API for [listing users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). But it doesn't support `personal` Microsoft account, it only supports `work or school` accounts. By the way, I'm not sure what is `Enterprise ID`, could you pls take a look at [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) to check if this API contained it?

I assume you have an asp.net core WEB API which is used to getting user list. So you should use code like below.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

Then an Azure AD application is required for the variables in code above. Pls follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application) to register the Azure AD app. Since my assumption is based on a web API, no need to add redirect URL here. Now we can get `tenantId  , clientId` in `Overview` blade, and created the client secret. We also need to modify `API permissions` blade and add required API permissions. What we need is `Application` permission `User.Read.All,User.ReadWrite.All,Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Enterprise ID is Employee ID

Comment: Please also check the link I shared in my original post. It is pulling some details but I am not sure it is coming from Azure AD or some other AD

Comment: Hi, I already checked the link and to be honest I don't know about on-prem AD. And I also checked the Ms graph API, I found the getting user api had the `employeeId`. So if you are sure to query Azure AD user inforamation, then what I shared can help you. But `employeeId` won't return by default, so you need to use `await graphClient.Users.Request().Select("employeeId,displayName,mail").GetAsync();`

Comment: Thanks for the code. Will get back to you.